# Foreach variable scope

Tags: c#, foreach

I am looking to understand and fix why the `prop` of type `PropertyInfo` does not exist within a `foreach` scope.

Code:

```
 foreach (var prop in props) // For each of type's properties
   if (prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Mappable)).Any())
       mapSwitch = 1;
 if (isLevelMatch(isContinueToGetData, mapSwitch, props))
 {
  if (model.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(obj) != null)
       comModel.FieldValueLet(prop.Name, model.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(obj));
   else
       comModel.FieldValueLet(prop.Name, DBNull.Value);
  }
```

Visual studio compiler is telling me that in the second `IF` statement this `prop` does not exist? Can anyone explain why this is?

Comment: Add `{` and `}` to `foreach`. Then you should see *scope* by yourself.

Comment: what a silly mistake! ha thanks!

Comment: @Sinatr please post as answer so i can accept

Comment: There are enough answers already I think. ;)

Comment: ha indeed :) @Sinatr

Comment: There are also enough down votes!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need brackets for the foreach block:

```
foreach (var prop in props) // For each of type's properties
{
   if (prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Mappable)).Any())
       mapSwitch = 1;

   if (isLevelMatch(isContinueToGetData, mapSwitch, props))
   {
      if (model.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(obj) != null)
        comModel.FieldValueLet(prop.Name, model.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(obj));
      else
        comModel.FieldValueLet(prop.Name, DBNull.Value);
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it was a silly mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any curly braces to denote a block of code to be run for each `prop` in `props`. As such, only the immediate next statement is.

If you add curly braces to how your current code is being evaluated, it would look like this:

```
foreach (var prop in props) // For each of type's properties
{
    if (prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Mappable)).Any())
    {
        mapSwitch = 1;
    }
}

if (isLevelMatch(isContinueToGetData, mapSwitch, props))
{
    if (model.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(obj) != null)
    {
        comModel.FieldValueLet(prop.Name, model.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(obj));
    }
    else
    {
        comModel.FieldValueLet(prop.Name, DBNull.Value);
    }
}
```

By the time you get to your `comModel.FieldValueLet` call, `prop` has been out of scope for a very long time.

Comment: thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Your brackets are not in the right places